# While not Stopping on Condition

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, variables, while-loop

how are you?
I am facing some issues with my code running on a snippet.

First: I do not know why when I try to run it, the loop does not finish

Second: One of my friends paste the code and ran on his computer and the loop finish but after running the second time the variables are sum with the new values inserted.

We are all using Google Chrome. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```
var i = 0;

var speed = parseInt(prompt('value 1'));
var long = parseInt(prompt('value 2'));
var vel2 = velocidad;
while (speed> 0){
    i++;
    if (i>speed){
        speed--;
    }
 console.log(speed);
}

sub_i = (i * vel2) - vel2;
console.log('Total i ' + i);
```

Comment: `i++` ... but you are summing 1 to what? you didn't initialize the `i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is to initialize `i = 0`